# Populating local storage data to an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After creating a game and implementing scores etc, I have saved the current logged in player's username along with his score to local storage.

```
/*Saves current logged in player to local storage*/
let player = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUsername");
```

```
function savePlayer(){
    /*sets logged in player + score + time*/
    let Player = [player, score];
    localStorage.setItem("Player",Player.toString());
}
```

I then call the function once the game is over. I have also created a high score table in HTML like so:

```
<body class = "score">

    <article>

        <!-- Table for TopScores -->

        <table align = "center">
            <tr>
                <td id= "title" colspan = "3"><h1>Top Scores</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</article>
</body>
```

I am having difficulty calling the player's username and his score to the high score table using localStorage.getItem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table row data from javascript, find below code snippet of jsfiddle link (https://jsfiddle.net/59u4ba0d/):

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var testObject = [{ 'name': 'James', 'score': 90, 'time': '16:00' }, { 
'name': 'Robert', 'score': 80, 'time': '15:00' }];
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));

var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < retrievedObject.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  tr += "<td>Name</td>" + "<td>" + retrievedObject[i].name + "</td></tr>";
  tr += "<td>Score</td>" + "<td>" + retrievedObject[i].score + "</td></tr>";
  tr += "<td>Time</td>" + "<td>" + retrievedObject[i].time + "</td></tr>";
  tbody.innerHTML += tr;
}
```

Comment: This is the working code, and if you are are unable to access localStorage / sessionStorage, please take a look at this article to enable and try again : https://help.trello.com/article/1093-enabling-localstorage